# Netbeans customize laravel blade commands color

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans, laravel-blade

I have been working on a Laravel project and was able to implement the code completion from the [IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper). What I am trying to find is a way to customize the color scheme for BLADE commands. Right now they are treated by Netbeans as plain HTML texts.

```
@extends('components.basic')

@section('html-title')
Welcome to Laravel
@endsection

@section('main-content')
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
@endsection
```

Comment: Use sublime, its lightweight and provide many Laravel packages like `Laravel snippets`, `Laravel blade highlighter` etc

Comment: Thanks but I'm really looking into a solution in Netbeans as this is the requirement.

Comment: Netbeans doesn't support blade at all. I doubt they intend to add support any time soon. [There was a bug report for this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=256599) a while ago but the NetBeans team basically did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as Netbeans is a open source app, it depends on the community to have overall features.

So, I've worked on developing a plugin for it :) .
It works for netbeans > **12.2** and it's on github https://github.com/haidubogdan/netbeans-php-blade-plugin

and the latest release at the moment (2022-04-18) is :
https://github.com/haidubogdan/netbeans-php-blade-plugin/releases

The plugin file which needs to be installed in netbeans is the *.nbm file.

Note: *It's still a work in progress, so features like auto-formatting or identation for blade files is not implemented yet. Due to this it's not ready to be deployed as a official plugin for the moment.*